# Execute a method each time StateHasChanged is called

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Suppose I have this blazor component (I'm using wasm):

```
<p>@name</p>

@code{
  private int id;
  public void SetId(int id) // will be called by another component that has a reference to this component
  {
    this.id = id;
    StateHasChanged();
  }

  private string name;
  private async Task UpdateName()
  {
    // httpService is injected
    this.name = await httpService.Get<string>($"api/getname?id={this.id}");
  }
}
```

How do I manage to call the `UpdateName` method each time `SetId` (hence `StateHasChanged`) is called ?

I tried calling it inside lifecycle methods `SetParametersAsync` and `OnParametersSetAsync`. But I think these methods are not being invoked each time `StateHasChanged` is called. Probably because the component has no parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will be called by another component that has a reference to this component

Then the preferred, clean approach is to not use `compRef.SetId(id)` but to pass the Id as a parameter:

```
 <MyComponent Id="id" />
```

Give your component a `[Parameter] public int Id {get; set; }` and call `UpdateName()` from `OnParameterSetAsync()`

---

Additional, a simple way with SetId().
You should normally avoid `async void` but in this case it is appropriate.

```
private int id;
public async void SetId(int id) // will be called by another component 
{
  this.id = id;

  // await so it is complete before the next line.
  await Updatename();            

  // when you know you always call it from the UI
  StateHasChanged();  

  //// or Invoke to avoid Cross-Threading issues. The await is optional.
  //await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```

The responsibility for calling StateHasChanged() clearly belongs to SetId().

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing that. I was wondering if there is a way to do it without getting the parent involved. I guess there ain't.

Comment: Well, it can be done but as I said, this is the cleanest way.